# MySQL - sum data by day intervals

Tags: mysql, intervals

I have such data in my table:

[image]

I need to calculate "Paid" field of UserID which reoccurs in 7 day intervals. In this example I will SUM(Paid) for UserID "01" because it occurs 2 times in 7 days interval.
I can calculate it programmaticaly, but only in such date intervals (2016-01-01 - 2016-01-07; 2016-01-07 - 2016-01-13; etc.).
Maybe there is some possibility to perform this calculation at MySQL level in any 7 day intervals? For example: 2016-01-01 - 2016-01-07; 2016-01-02 - 2016-01-08; 2016-10-10 - 2016-10-16; etc.

Comment: Take a look at the week() function of MySQL. Presumably you could sum paid group by UserID and week(date).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the method `WEEK()` returns the week number based on the calendar year, meaning that for 2016: 1st Jan, 2nd Jan and 3rd Jan would return 0, but 4th Jan would return 1, which to my understanding does not fit the requirements.

I would suggest:

`` SELECT `UserID`, SUM(`Paid`) FROM `table` GROUP BY DATEDIFF(`Date`, (SELECT MIN(`Date`) FROM `table`)) DIV 7, `UserID` ``